# Css boxes aren't shown beside each other properly

Tags: html, css

I made two boxes which one of them is a number and second one is an image and styled them by css. Although everything is the same why the left box is a little appear smaller in the bottom if you notice where did I make mistake?

```css
.flex-container
/* to put boxes in a row */

{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  left: 30%;
}

.first {
  padding: 20px;
}

.card {
  width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-align: center;
}

.header
/* Calendar description */

{
  background-color: rgb(144, 204, 194);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 210px;
}

.narrow
/* the narrow white band*/

{
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.text {
  color: rgb(223, 177, 26);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.text:hover {
  color: rgb(144, 204, 194);
}

.day
/* to specify the day style which is smaller */

{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="first">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>2</h1>
        <p class="day">Sat.</p>
      </div>
      <div Class="narrow" style="height:53px">
        <p class="text">May, 2018</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="first">
    <div class="card">
      <div>
        <img src="https://media.cntraveler.com/photos/5ac3980ba90ec7611095c8ed/master/w_820,c_limit/GettyImages-637176190.jpg" alt="Paris" width="250" height="230">
      </div>

      <div Class="narrow">
        <p class="text">Where is here?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because of this `style="height:53px"` defining a fixed height for one element isn't healthy if you want both cards to have same height.

Answer (score 0):

this how flexboxes work. In the case of a row, the height of the children is equal for every element, but only for direct children, not for all the descendants.

In your case, the easiest way to fix this would be to remove the containers with class `first`, and have the containers with class `card` as direct children of the flex container.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the height: 53px and provided **display: flex** to .first

```css
.flex-container
/* to put boxes in a row */

{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  left: 30%;
}

.first {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-align: center;
}

.header
/* Calendar description */

{
  background-color: rgb(144, 204, 194);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 210px;
}

.narrow
/* the narrow white band*/

{
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.text {
  color: rgb(223, 177, 26);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.text:hover {
  color: rgb(144, 204, 194);
}

.day
/* to specify the day style which is smaller */

{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="first">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>2</h1>
        <p class="day">Sat.</p>
      </div>
      <div Class="narrow">
        <p class="text">May, 2018</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="first">
    <div class="card">
      <div>
        <img src="https://media.cntraveler.com/photos/5ac3980ba90ec7611095c8ed/master/w_820,c_limit/GettyImages-637176190.jpg" alt="Paris" width="250" height="230">
      </div>

      <div Class="narrow">
        <p class="text">Where is here?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```